# How to read this C++ function

Tags: c++

Maybe someone here could help me to understand more about C++

While reading about Unreal Engine 4, I came across this function which is used as the following

```
class ClassSample1
{
public:
    Babu* pBabu; //0x022C
};

void SetFuncton(Babu* param1, bool param2)
{
    (*(int(__fastcall**)(Babu*, bool))(*(DWORD64*)param1 + 0x38))(param1, param2);
}
```

What I want to know.

1. What will this function produce?
2. What datatype will this function produce?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a virtual function call `param1->??(param2)`, but written without access to the true class definition. There's nothing fancy here, other than what you already see. The function parameter is `bool` (ignoring `Babu *`, which is `this`), and it returns an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to know.
>
> 1. What will this function produce?

That's the fun part, from what you've shown, nobody knows!

> 2. What datatype will this function produce?

I guess the answer is "nothing", `SetFunction()` returns void, but this appears to be calling some kind of class parameter setter so it will probably have side effects.

Let's break this down a bit:

```
(int(__fastcall**)(Babu*, bool))
```

This declares a pointer to a pointer to a function, where the function returns `int` and has two parameters, one of type pointer to `Babu`, and one of type `bool`. This function should also use the [__fastcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fastcall?view=msvc-170) calling convention.

```
*(DWORD64*)param1 + 0x38
```

This is a compound statement which casts `param1` to a pointer to `DWORD64` and then reads the `DWORD64` value at that address and adds 0x38 to it. Note that in the MSVC ABI, the vtable pointer is the first element of a class, so if `param1` is a pointer to an instance of `Babu` this statement is reading the vtable pointer of `Babu`, and adding 0x38 to it.

Putting these together:

```
*(int(__fastcall**)(Babu*, bool))(*(DWORD64*)param1 + 0x38)
```

This says: take whatever is stored at memory address `param1` (which is probably the vtable pointer), add 0x38 to it, cast this to a pointer to a pointer to a function, read this resulting address to produce a pointer to a function of the type described above. As @HolyBlackCat mentioned in the comments, this is most likely a virtual method lookup on the class `Babu`.

The last little bit: `(param1, param2)`, is just the actual call to the function with `param1` and `param2` as arguments. Note that in any class method call, there is an implicit `this` pointer which gets passed as the first argument.

From all of this it's fair to deduce that class `Babu` has some set of virtual methods, and there's one at offset 0x38 which takes `bool` as its one non-implicit parameter. What happens after this is anybody's guess. At the risk of being dismissive I would consider it somewhat miraculous if it returns with your machine intact at all.

Comment: Can we continue this in room chat?

Comment: Very good breakdown. Personally, I probably would have written a helper `struct` to define the vtable and avoid all the knarly pointer arithmetic and type-casting, though.

Comment: Sorry @LambertoFredrickNababan probably used up my Stack Overflow time budget for the day, but if you have further questions I'm happy to answer them here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I totally agree, I'm scratching my head trying to put myself in the shoes of whoever wrote this. This particular approach would have actually been simpler if it was just written in inline asm, if you're going to do it in "real" C++ you might as well use the language and make it readable.

Comment: @JonReeves after I tried to create log and I got this (00007FF6AF61FA20)(1).
(00007FF6AF61FA20) refer to (*(int(__fastcall**)(Babu*, bool))(*(DWORD64*)param1 + 0x38))
AND (1) refer to (param1, param2). What (00007FF6AF61FA20)(1) means?

Comment: @LambertoFredrickNababan if I understood you correctly, then 00007FF6AF61FA20 is the memory address of the virtual method that's being called.